# Storing input from file into struct in C

Tags: c, input, struct, io

So I have an input file that I'm scanning in. I also have an array of structs. I need to store the information from this input into the structs. I'm able to read the input file and print it back out but im not sure how to go about storing this information in my structs. The issue seems to be that I can't access my structs properly in the function that scans the file. Below is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* make an array of structs that contain the ponds, and the ponds contain pointers to the circular lists */

struct pond_struct {
    char name[20];
    int sequence;
    int failfish;
    int eatingcounter;
    int threshold;
    struct pond_struct *next;
    struct pond_struct *prev;
};

typedef struct pond_struct pond;

struct pond_list_struct {
    pond *head;
    pond *tail;
};

typedef struct pond_list_struct pond_list;

int get_number_of_ponds(FILE *ifp) 
{
    char s[128];
    int num;
    
    //get the first line of the file
    fgets (s, 127, ifp);

    if(isspace(s[0]))
    {
        fgets (s, 127, ifp);
    }
    
    sscanf(s, "%d", &num);
    
    return num;
}

void remove_crlf(char *s)
{
    char *t = s + strlen(s);

    // t begins at the null sentinel at the end of s.

    t--;

    /* t is now at the last character of s - unless s didn't contain any characters, in which
       case, t is now *BEFORE* s.  We have to keep checking for that. */

    /* We repeat until EITHER t slides to the left of s, OR we find a character that is not a
       line feed (\n) or a carriage return (\r). */

    while ((t >= s) && (*t == '\n' || *t == '\r'))
    {
        *t = '\0'; // Clobber the character t is pointing at.
        t--;      // Decrement t.
    }
}

void get_next_nonblank_line(FILE *ifp, char *s, int max_length)
{
    s[0] = '\0';

    while (s[0] == '\0')
    {
        fgets(s, max_length, ifp);
        remove_crlf(s);
    }
}

void read_pond (FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp, pond ponds)
{
    char s[128];
    char full_line[128];
    int nponds;
    int i;
    int pond_number;
    char name[128];
    //char sequence_string[128];
    int sequence;
    //char failfish_string[128];
    int failfish;
    //char eatingcounter_string[128];
    int eatingcounter;
    //char threshold_string[128];
    int threshold;
    
    nponds = get_number_of_ponds(ifp);
    printf("There are %d ponds\n", nponds);
    fprintf(ofp, "There are %d ponds\n", nponds);
    
    for (i = 0; i < nponds; i++)
    {
        get_next_nonblank_line(ifp, full_line, 127);
        sscanf(s, "%d %s %d %d %d", &pond_number, name, &failfish, &eatingcounter, &threshold);
        printf("The pond name is %s\n", full_line);
    }
}

/* void print_pond (FILE *ofp, pond ponds, char* name, int sequence, int failfish, int eatingcounter, int threshold)
{
    fprintf(ofp, "%s is pond number %d. The number of failfish is %d, the eating counter is %d, and the threshold is %d\n", name, sequence, failfish, eatingcounter, threshold);
} */

int main (void)
{
    
    FILE *ifp;
    FILE *ofp;
    
    int nponds;
    int i;
    char name[128];
    int sequence;
    int failfish;
    int eatingcounter;
    int threshold;
    
    pond ponds[10];
    
    // change input file name
    ifp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    ofp = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    
    read_pond(ifp, ofp, ponds[0]);
    
    /* for (i = 0; i < nponds; i++)
    {
        print_pond(ofp, ponds[i], name, sequence, failfish, eatingcounter, threshold);
    } */
    
    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the posted code contains LOTS of unused variables and parameters.   The posted code is missing the statement; `#include <ctype.h>` which is needed for the `isspace()` function

Comment: You want to pass a pointer to your ponds table to the load function. You are passing the first entry in the table instead.

Comment: Looking beyond the lack of nearly all error checking to speak of, there is some apparent confusion of whether to load a linked list, an array, a single instance, or in the case of the unused by-value argument `ponds` in `read_pond`, none of the above. The `sscanf` in `read_pond`, for example, loads some local variables (we hope, since there is no error checking), then promptly discards them all.

Comment: regarding: `ifp = fopen("input.txt", "r");` and `ofp = fopen("output.txt", "w");`  for robust code, always immediately check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  if not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "fopen for input file failed" );`, then clean up,, then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: @johnelemans what do you mean by the load function? And by table are you referring to my input file?

Comment: @WhozCraig The goal of the variables with the sscanf is to load those variables with the values from the input file. I realize that those get overridden every time it loops. What im trying to figure out is how to assign whats i those variables to my structs.

Comment: regarding: `read_pond(ifp, ofp, ponds[0]);` this is passing the contents of the first entry in the array `ponds[]`  However, what you want to do is pass the address of the array.  Suggest: `read_pond( ifp, ofp, ponds );`  (remembering that a reference to the bare name of an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array)

Comment: regarding: `fgets (s, 127, ifp);

    if(isspace(s[0]))
    {
        fgets (s, 127, ifp);
    }`   This seems to indicate that the first line in the input file 'may' be blank.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @user3629249 making your suggested change to read_pond causes an error that says incompatible type for argument. it also says it expected pond (aka struct pond_struct) but argument is of type pond*

Comment: regarding this function: `void remove_crlf(char *s)`  much better to use: `s[ strspn( s, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: regarding; `s[0] = '\0';

    while (s[0] == '\0')
    {
        fgets(s, max_length, ifp);
        remove_crlf(s);
    }`  a 'blank' line will contain a '\n', not  a '\0'. and the contents of the array 's[]' will start with '\n', not a NUL byte.

Comment: regarding: `sscanf(s, "%d", &num);`  this function can fail to input an integer.  Always check the returned value ( not the parameter value)  the `scanf()` family of functions return the number of successful 'input format conversion specifiers (or EOF)  in the current statement suggest: `if( sscanf(s, "%d", &num) != 1 ) { //handle error and exit }`

Comment: this function signature: `void read_pond (FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp, pond ponds)` should be: `void read_pond (FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp, pond *ponds)`  Notice the `*`

Comment: this statement: `sscanf(s, "%d %s %d %d %d", &pond_number, name, &failfish, &eatingcounter, &threshold);`  would be better as: `sscanf(  s, "%d %19s %d %d %d", &ponds[i].pond_number, ponds[i].name, &ponds[i].failfish, &ponds[i].eatingcounter, &ponds[i].threshold);`  Note: the `%19s` is to avoid buffer overflow as the `%s` always appends a NUL byte to the input

Answer (score 0):

`typedef struct {`
    `int    nMyInt;`
    `char    szDate[6];`
    `char    filler[2];`
`} _MY_STRUCT;`
`_MY_STRUCT stMS;`
`stMS.nMyInt = 2;`
`strcpy(stMS.szDate,"10/19/2020");`

1. Update your structure so byte-alignment storage is 8 bytes using a filler.
2. Use &stMS with fread/fwrite and sizeof(_MY_STRUCT) to read/write data.

Comment: Where, in the posted code, is there any evidence whatsoever to indicate the data is stored as a packed octet stream of machine-dependent form? Quite the contrary, literally *everything* in the OP posted code indicates the data is stored, read, and (unsuccessfully) processed as *text*.